# Why 11.10 says plymouth errors and "Checking battery state..."?

Tags: 11.10, plymouth

I've just installed new Ubuntu 11.10. The installation was successful. But when I start the Ubuntu, the splash screen does not work, and I get error (always some of these) "mountall: Plymouth command failed", "mountall: Connect to Plymouth was lost" or "Checking battery state..."

I'm sorry, if the error messages are incorrect because I translated two first of them from Finnish (my system is in Finnish) to English, so they maybe couldn't be just right.

I have already asked from our Finnish community, but they couldn't answer. Could anybody here?

Comment: If this is a new install - please add to your grub boot options "nomodeset xforcevesa acpi=off" - if this works - try combinations of these 3 options to find which allows you to boot correctly.

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: try the following AU Question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834

Comment: set it for "nomodeset quiet splash", but it still says "Checking battery state...". Secondly it went longer than before. What could I do?

Comment: have you tried "acpi=off" and "xforcevesa" and "xforcevesa acpi=off" etc etc?? - dont forget - Since this is an Question and Answer site, add what you have tried as an edit of your question.

Comment: also - press shift on boot to display your grub - choose recovery mode console.  type `more /var/logs/lightdm` - is their an error in there with ".Xauthority" ??  if there is try `sudo rm /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority` and rebooting.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I started recovery mode and opened admin's terminal and I typed that command in terminal. It says that the file isn't exist.

And I have also tried your commands like "ro   quiet splash xforcevesa acpi=off;
acpi=off;
xforcevesa;
[none];
xforcevesa acpi=off;
quiet splash xforcevesa;
quiet splash;
ro   quiet splash xforcevesa;
quiet splash acpi=off;
ro   quiet splash acpi=off;
quiet splash xforcevesa acpi=off"
but none of them didn't work.

Comment: Actually the error messages oftenly comes after "Starting Lightdm".

Comment: @Aleksi I [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/850895) that sounds similar a while ago. Your issue could be hardware-related. Could you post some more information on what hardware (i.e., monitor, graphics) you are using, and whether any of the workarounds mentioned in the bug report help you? If so, you may want to mark yourself as affected there.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem sometimes when I have updated from beta 11.10,
I dont know what the exact problem is but it shows starting lightdm fail then it stops at checking bettery state,
so u need to start lightdm
press ctrl + alt + F2
login and type sudo lightdm
it should work.
and for me I have installed gdm removed lightdm

Answer (score 1):

After a clean install:

1. Let the system start booting until it stops near the "battery state" message
2. alt+f1 to open the terminal. Log in with your credentials.
3. sudo apt-get remove nvidia-173
4. sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
5. if you've run "startx" earlier: rm -f ~/.Xauthority
6. sudo reboot
7. Happy Ubuntu'ing!

The issue seems to be with the Nvidia drivers. When you run startx, the X server looks for nvidia-173 (or 171, can't quite remember), but they seem to be faulty. Uninstalling the old driver and installing a newer one fixed the issue for me.